# Django: Set charfield default as variable composed of ForeignKeys

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to set a default value for a CharField in a Django model as a composite of two ForeignKeys contained within the model itself.

Here is the model in questions and the methods I attempted:

```
class SensorParameter(models.Model):
    sensor                  = models.ForeignKey(Sensor)
    parameter               = models.ForeignKey(Parameter)
    parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=default_name)
    live_value              = models.FloatField()

    @staticmethod
    def default_name():
        return str(self.sensor.name) + " - " + str(parameter.parameter_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sensor.name) + ' - ' + str(self.parameter)

    def __key(self):
        return self.sensor.id, self.parameter.id

    def __eq__(self, y):
        return isinstance(y, self.__class__) and self.__key() == y.__key()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())

    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('sensor','parameter_name_userdef'),)
```

Explanation:

This will be a table of all **Parameters** that belong to a **Sensor**. The name of the **Parameter** instance is generated in another table by the **Sensor** instance, and the combination of both of those is presented in this table. The user can then opt to change the name of the **Parameter** for that **Sensor** only, through this table.

The idea is, by default, the parameter_name_userdef(ined) will be a string of **Sensor Name** + " - " **Parameter Name**. But through a form and AJAX the user can change it to whatever string they want.

I tried the following (assume "max_length=100, blank=False" are set):

```
parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(default=str(sensor.name) + " - " str(parameter.parameter_name)
```

> AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'parameter_name' (It does!)

---

```
parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(default=str(sensor + parameter))
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +; 'ForeignKey' and 'ForeignKey'

---

```
parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(default=str(sensor.name, parameter.parameter_name)
```

> AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'parameter_name'

---

```
default_sensor = str(sensor.name)
default_param = str(parameter.parameter_name)
default_string = default_sensor + " - " + default_param
parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(default=default_string)
```

> AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'parameter_name'

---

```
parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=default_name)
live_value = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @staticmethod
    def default_name():
        return str(self.sensor.name) + " - " + str(parameter.parameter_name)
```

> NameError: name 'default_name' is not defined

---

If I try with:

```
parameter_name_userdef  = models.CharField(default=str(sensor, parameter)
```

This works, but it's not quite what I need, as the self.**str** of **Sensor** and **Parameter** are different than **Sensor.name** and **Parameter.parameter_name**. (**Sensor.__str__** includes serial number, and **Parameter.__str__** includes a "run" value)

(Also, I realise the naming discrepancy between Sensor.name and Parameter.parameter_name, I'll be changing this soon but they're used in a few dozen places each so it'll probably take a while)

Any help with setting that default name to take from 2 other models?

Comment: You can't do any of these things. Even if you could make the default point to the method, staticmethods don't have any access to the instance - that's why they're static - and don't accept a self parameter, so you can't access `self.sensor` etc. This is just not something you can do in the model definition.

Comment: Not to mention, at the time the defaults are applied the foreign keys won't have any values either, so there is no point in trying to use those values.

Comment: So I should at least be happy to use Parameter as the default!

Where would I set the proper default, if not in the model? I'm still new at Django, and there's loads to cover!

Thanks for your quick input!

Comment: You could do this in the save method, or pass an initial value to the form from your edit view.